# Changing lanes on a freeway

Tags: sentence-construction, idiomatic-language

What are some idiomatic AmE sayings to mean "to change lanes?"

```
"Get over (to the other lane)" I hear this one from my roommate.
"Cross (to the other lane)?"
"Cross over?"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Switch lanes
>
> Change lanes
>
> Get over to the other lane
>
> Drift into the other lane(though this means a lane change by accident)
>
> Move into the other lane
>
> Cross into the other lane(this usually means to temporarily move into the other lane)

Are a few ways you can say it.